# Elasticsearch combining Filter with Bool by a Must

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to combine a "filter" with a "bool"/"should" inside a "must". The following query is automatically generated by an application (hence the nesting). How must the query look like to have an AND condition between the wildcard condition and the filter statement?

```
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [],
              "must_not": [],
              "should": [],
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "attachment.content_type.keyword": "video/*"
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "must": [],
                  "must_not": [],
                  "filter": [
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "status.keyword": [
                          "xxx"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a AND between those two conditions, then you simply need this. Since both constraints are exact matches without any scoring involved, then bool/filter is all you need.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "attachment.content_type.keyword": "video/*"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "status.keyword": [
              "xxx"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You can nest everything, but it doesn't bring anything

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": {
              "wildcard": {
                "attachment.content_type.keyword": "video/*"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": {
              "terms": {
                "status.keyword": [
                  "xxx"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I still keep the should before the wildcard and the filter before the terms?